# Difference between Html.RenderAction and Html.Action

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Does anybody know what's the difference between [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx) and [Html.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Html.Action()` – Outputs string

`Html.RenderAction()` – Renders directly to response stream

If the action returns a large amount of HTML, then rendering directly to the response stream provides better performance than outputting a string.

Comment: So when would you use Html.Action if RenderAction gives better performance?

Comment: @user76071 from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction) with Action you can put the result in a variable or return it from a function.

Comment: Better performance? Barely. This is a bad case of premature optimization. Unless you are outputting a huge wiki article, the differences are negligible. Personally, I find Html.Action more readable and only use Html.RenderAction if I am in a code block.

Comment: Below article In answer below, states RenderAction is better when rendering a lot of HTML, (like a partial View.)  That's why I like it better.

Answer (score 27):

> The difference between the two is that
>   Html.RenderAction will render the
>   result directly to the Response (which
>   is more efficient if the action
>   returns a large amount of HTML)
>   whereas Html.Action returns a string
>   with the result.

check out [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) for a detailed explanation