# cannot implicitly convert type void to object. .NET MVC PartialViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

I have the following controller action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public virtual PartialViewResult ListActions(int id)
{
    var actions = meetingActionRepository.GetAllMeetingActions(id);

    return PartialView(actions);
}
```

And the following action link (using t4MVC and the razor syntax)

```
<p>
   @Html.RenderAction(MVC.MeetingActions.ListActions(Model.MeetingId))
</p>
```

However this gives me the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type void to object

As far as i can tell the controller action is ok, so what could be giving me this error?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Like this:

```
<p>
    @Html.Action(MVC.MeetingActions.ListActions(Model.MeetingId))
</p>
```

or if you insist on `RenderAction` like this:

```
<p>
    @{Html.RenderAction(MVC.MeetingActions.ListActions(Model.MeetingId));}
</p>
```

Personally I prefer the first, makes fewer keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you. Funky syntax there. I assume that's the razor way of doing <%html instead of <%=Html ? What's the difference between Action and Renderaction anyway. Phil Haack says RenderAction is more efficient?

Comment: @Doozer1979, yeah, exactly, that's the Razor way.

Comment: This also works : {Html.RenderAction(MVC.MeetingActions.ListActions(Model.MeetingId));}, so using @ is not necessary.

Answer (score 50):

I had the same issue. What worked for me is to encapsulate the expression it in **curly brackets**.

`@{Html.RenderPartial("viewName", Model);}`

Comment: This worked for me, however I have no idea why adding curling brackets would work.  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @BradThiessen It works because ASP.NET MVC is quite frankly a shoddy framework full of glaring holes and poor design decisions. I just came across this too. Who knows why, but my patience is wearing thin with MVC.

Comment: @BradThiessen `RenderPartial()` is a void, using `@` you say the Razor to print it which is not possible as it doesn't produce any output content!

Answer (score 45):

[Html.Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402898%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) should work as well :)

```
@Html.Partial("View", Model);
```

Answer (score 6):

[Difference between Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action)

Different things for different purposes.
Check out the above link.