# Function call fails in inline statement, but not in block

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

In my index.cshtml file I'm trying to render a partial view, but I'm having some problems doing this with inline razor syntax.

The following works and renders the partial view:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_View", Model.model); }
```

The following gives an error:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_View", Model.model)
```

The error is:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
```

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about inline code in razor?

Comment: `RenderPartial()` is a void, using `@` you instruct Razor to print it. [You can't print void. You need `@Html.Partial()`, which returns an `IHtmlString` that can be printed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot implicitly convert type void to object. .NET MVC PartialViewResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927586/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-void-to-object-net-mvc-partialviewresult)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is the same problem, but does not contain an answer to the problem, although it contains the solution. What CodeCaster said is the answer.

Comment: Both comments are mine. There is no question in your question, so I picked the duplicate that applies most.