# The difference between Html.Action and Html.RenderAction

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I've been trying to figure out the difference between RenderAction and Action. I don't know if I'm so concerned about the differences at this point, as to why I can't get RenderAction to work. From what I can tell, I'm passing in the correct parameters. The overload I'm using seems to be the same for both:

```
@Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller, Route)

@Html.Action("Breadcrumb", "Navigation", new {SeoUrl = Model.CarlineBucket.SEOURLName})

@Html.RenderAction("Breadcrumb", "Navigation", new {SeoUrl = Model.CarlineBucket.SEOURLName})
```

I get a compilation error when I try and use RenderAction:

> CS1502: The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Any tips or hints? Should I not even be bothering with RenderAction?

Comment: Both of these methods allow you to call into an action method from a view and output the results of the action in place within the view. The difference between the two is that Html.RenderAction will render the result directly to the Response (which is more efficient if the action returns a large amount of HTML) whereas Html.Action returns a string with the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Breadcrumb", "Navigation", new {SeoUrl = Model.CarlineBucket.SEOURLName});}
```

`@Html.RenderAction()` generates a write call to output something on the page and in your case you are not doing so because `RenderAction` renders the result directly to the Response.

Instead of

```
@Html.RenderAction()
```

Use

```
@{Html.RenderAction();}
```

Comment: This did indeed do the trick. When I read that RenderAction renders the result directly to the response, I don't really understand what that means. Also, can you explain or point me where to find the difference of @{HTML()} vs @HTML()

Comment: @{..} is a code block, and @.. is an Expression, have a look at - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: I believe you need a semicolon at the end of the statement, just before the closing }. Otherwise razor will throw an HttpCompileException.

Comment: There is a great video explaining PArtial vs RenderPArtial.. this will clarify the {Html ;}  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SABg7RyjX-4

Answer (score 18):

From [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx):

> The difference between the two is that
>   `Html.RenderAction` will render the
>   result directly to the Response (which
>   is more efficient if the action
>   returns a large amount of HTML)
>   whereas `Html.Action` returns a string
>   with the result.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of `Html.RenderAction` is `void` that means it directly render the responses in View where  return type of Html.Action  is  `MvcHtmlString` you can catch its render view in the controller and modified it also by using following method

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

This will return the Html string of the View.

Answer (score 0):

**Html.Action** and **Html.RenderAction** are extension methods used as reusable portion inside parent page.

**Html.RenderAction** return void and it will render the result directly to the Response Stream (More efficient & fast) whereas return type of **Html.Action** is MvcHtmlString which can be manipulated prior to write in response stream.

*Html.Action helper Syntax:* 
`@Html.Action("Action", "Controller", new { "routeData" })`

*Html.Action helper Syntax:* 
`@{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new { "routeData" }); }`

According to me, use Html.Action only if you wants to perform some modifications in string else use Html.RenderAction.