# ASP .net MVC - Master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am new to MVC. Where to write C# code to common functionalists that is comming under master page(Eg: Login)?

Answer (score 0):

Create partial *.ascx view for login in shared folder and add it to master page like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LoginUserControl"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Html.RenderAction()` / `Html.Action()`, which do not require a Model to be passed.
That is, what @x2 suggested is OK if the control is not dependent on any model, but if it is, use one of the above methods.

See: [The difference between Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810598/the-difference-between-html-action-and-html-renderaction)

And: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx