# Usual practice for re-usable elements in MVC 5.0 - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have recently been writing controllers for specific pages... so let's say we have 2 controllers:

```
HomeController
JamesController
```

On the Home page, I have a dropdown list that contains all James items...
On the James list page, I have a dropdown list that contains all James items...

Evidently, I'm gonna be using the same code to get a full list of James back and present it to a view:

```
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        IEnumerable<James> jamesList = repository.James();
        return View(jamesList);
    }
```

What's the usual practice for re-usable bits of code like that? Do you have 2 methods doing the same job where they are required... or do you have ANOTHER called JamesDropDownController and just call upon that from within the 2 views that the 2 controllers are pushing data to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create `JamesDropDownController` with `GetList` action and call it from `RenderAction`

```
public class JamesDropDownController 
{
 public ActionResult GetList()
 {
  List<SelectItem> allItems= new List<SelectItem>(); // from DB
  return View("JamesDropDown", allItems);
 }
}
```

***Views/Shared/JamesDropDown.cshtml***

```
@model List<SelectItem>

@Html.DropDownListFor("JamesDropDown",model);
```

In all the views that required James Drop down

```
 @Html.RenderAction("GetList","JamesDropDown")
```

Comment: Should it be a partial view or just a normal view inside the shared folder?

Comment: @JamesT, partial view(i.e without a _Layout specified)

Comment: Beautiful, thanks buddy. good to know i'm not the only one now hehe :)

Comment: Actually, Html.RenderAction was saying "cannot implicitly convert type void to object" I tried Html.Action instead and that now fires the controller and view correctly but also adds a layout regardless of me not adding one to the Partial View itself

Comment: Oh I have to set the fact that it has "" Layout explicitly.. cool. so RenderAction does not work but Action does!

Comment: @James T, syntax @{ Html.RenderAction("ActionName","ControllerName"); }

Comment: That solved it... The difference is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action