# News page with headline list in sidebar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm pretty new to MVC.  I'm trying to create a page where a news story is pulled from a SQL Server database to populate the main area of the page, while I have a sidebar where all the headlines are listed.  I've tried using a partial view for the sidebar.

Here's the code from the controller which populates the views:

```
        public ActionResult _ArticleList()
        {
            return View(db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList());
        }    

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Articles articles = db.Articles.Find(id);
            if (articles == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articles);
```

My main view - Details.cshtml

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Articles

    <div id="container">

        {
        <div id="main" class="col-md-9">

            <h2> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Headline)</h2>
            <p style="white-space:pre-line">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightnav" class="col-md-3">
            @Html.Partial("_ArticleList")

        </div>
    </div>
```

and my partial view - _ArticleList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Articles>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="/Details/@item.id"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Headline)</a>
    <br>
}
```

I'm getting a conflict between `@model MyApplication.Models.Articles` in the main view and `@model IEnumerable<MyApplication.Models.Articles>` in the partial.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.Partial("_ArticleList")
// and
@{Html.RenderPartial("_ArticleList");}
```

Means, load the CSHTML page and put it here with the current model (with Render versions more efficient).  They are *controllerless* meaning there is no call to a controller.

If you need to load a HTML in a separate controller/method context, then you would use one of the following.

```
@Html.Action("_ArticleList")
// and
@{Html.RenderAction("_ArticleList");}
```

Again, using the [Render Option is more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action).

The issue you may have is that both Action/Render will render out with any layouts you have, causing a really weird output (html tags within previous body tags possibly).  To prevent this, instead of calling `View()` you can call [`PartialView()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) in your controller.

```
public ActionResult _ArticleList()
{
  return PartialView(db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList());
}
```

I would also suggest that you *lock down* this method so that it can only be called by `Action()` or `RenderAction()` by using the [ChildActionOnlyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _ArticleList()
{
  return PartialView(db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. `Html.RenderAction` got me past the YSOD, but as you predicted it really messed up my Bootstrap layout.  `return PartialView` solved that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@Html.Partial("_ArticleList")` with `@Html.Action("_ArticleList", "Articles")`, that will run to your Articles controller and should use the partial view you created.