# Google Workspace Addon Dynamic dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script

What I want to achieve is to create a dynamic dropdown (fetch from a database and based on the selection display a list of items).

The problem is I can't get the `onChangeAction` to work this is on my home card so I configured the action to trigger the function of my home card.

```json
              {
                widgets: [
                  {
                    selectionInput: {
                      type: 'DROPDOWN',
                      name: 'projects',
                      label: 'Select project',
                      items: projects.map((project) => ({
                        text: project.name,
                        value: project.id,
                        selected: project.id === selectedProjectId,
                      })),
                      onChangeAction: {
                        function:
                          'https://xxxxxxxx/onCalendarHomePageOpen',
                        parameters: [],
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              }
```

I see this error:

> Cannot find field: action in message google.apps.card.v1.SubmitFormResponse

Then I add render_actions and the onChange works, but the rest state breaks.

This same thing happens when I try to navigate back to the home card from another one.

I just noticed you mention `renderActions` in the common card ui generator, and then `render_actions` in the card ui generators, I'm not sure about what's the difference.

Thank you very much

Comment: I am having hard time understanding your goal towards your question. Please edit your question to narrow which hurdle you need help this way the community will have better understanding of your case. Based on what I have understood. This should fix the question about render action and action [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955261/difference-between-html-renderaction-and-html-action).

Comment: About the breaking of state are you referring to the navigation of the cards that breaks? Have you had the chance to check this article? [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/navigation\#navigation\_methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/navigation#navigation_methods). I cannot give answers yet as their is a lack of focus in regards to your question. Please edit it.

Comment: Thanks @Babanana, the goal is to fetch items from a database and dynamically update the card. I could find a tutorial with the solution and posted it as an answer. I will edit the question to make it more clear. Regarding renderAction I understand they do the same, then why one breaks stuff and the other doesn't in some cases?

Comment: They actually have different output, As per the post that answers this on the stackoverflow link I provided. Action outputs sting while RenderAction renders a response stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workspace-add-on-nodejs-cloudrun#5

You have to create a new endpoint, build the card and pass it to the updateCard method.

**Fetch tasks**

```
app.post('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const event = req.body;
    const user = await userInfo(event);
    const tasks = await listTasks(user.sub);
    const card = buildCard(req, tasks);
    const responsePayload = {
        action: {
            navigations: [{
                pushCard: card
            }]
        }
    };
    res.json(responsePayload);
}));
```

**Add task**

```js
app.post('/newTask', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const event = req.body;
    const user = await userInfo(event);

    const formInputs = event.commonEventObject.formInputs || {};
    const newTask = formInputs.newTask;
    if (!newTask || !newTask.stringInputs) {
        return {};
    }

    const task = {
        text: newTask.stringInputs.value[0],
        created: new Date()
    };
    await addTask(user.sub, task);

    const tasks = await listTasks(user.sub);
    const card = buildCard(req, tasks);
    const responsePayload = {
        renderActions: {
            action: {
                navigations: [{
                    updateCard: card
                }],
                notification: {
                    text: 'Task added.'
                },
            }
        }
    };
    res.json(responsePayload);
}));
```

**buildCard method**

```
function buildCard(req, tasks) {
    const baseUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}${req.baseUrl}`;
    // Input for adding a new task
    const inputSection = {
        widgets: [
            {
                textInput: {
                    label: 'Task to add',
                    name: 'newTask',
                    value: '',
                    onChangeAction: {
                        function: `${baseUrl}/newTask`,
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    };
    const taskListSection = {
        header: 'Your tasks',
        widgets: []
    };
    if (tasks && tasks.length) {
        // Create text & checkbox for each task
        tasks.forEach(task => taskListSection.widgets.push({
            decoratedText: {
                text: task.text,
                wrapText: true,
                switchControl: {
                    controlType: 'CHECKBOX',
                    name: 'completedTasks',
                    value: task[datastore.KEY].id,
                    selected: false,
                    onChangeAction: {
                        function: `${baseUrl}/complete`,
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    } else {
        // Placeholder for empty task list
        taskListSection.widgets.push({
            textParagraph: {
                text: 'Your task list is empty.'
            }
        });
    }
    const card = {
        sections: [
            inputSection,
            taskListSection,
        ]
    }
    return card;
}
```